# How does xavier_initializer() know the activation?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

How does tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer() know the activation functions?

The standard deviation to initialize well depends on the non-linearity used. Right? How then does tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer() know whats going on?

Take the following case:

```
W = tf.get_variable("W", shape=[784, 256],
           initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

This W does something to X and then the result is passed to a tanh or relu or have you. Now, the initializer is in the W. How does tensorflow figure the activation out? Or do I have to intervene, knowing the activation I am going to use?

Looked at the arguments in [tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard9/tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer.md) and there I can chose unifrom or normal distribution. But that doesn't solve it, right?

Answer (score 0):

> The standard deviation to initialize well depends on the non-linearity used. Right?

No. The Xavier initialization do not need to know anything about the non linearity used by the network.

In fact, the Xavier initialization is just the initialization of the weights picking the value from a random distribution with mean = 0 and variance = `1/<number_of_inputs>`.

When declaring a variable, you pass the `shape` parameter. The first dimension of the shape parameter is the `<number_of_inputs>`.

Maybe you're looking for the He initialization, that is defined specifically for ReLU e PReLU, but even in that case, the variable initialization do not need to know what non-linearity will follow